# Installing Ubuntu along win8

Tags: system-installation

I'm new to Linux distro. I have 750 GB HDD on my PC and I made it 2 primary partitions and 3 logical partitions and I had windows 7 installed on one primary partition the other is empty for linux distro.

All I want is to install Ubuntu 12.10/Linux mint 13/fedora 17 and i heard that UEFI base boot doesn't apply to Linux and its already been disabled in my windows 8 boot menu and I also know that NTFS doesn't apply to Linux.

So please help to choose right Linux distro and give me every step by step to install Linux distro on my PC and i want to know if I can make one partition in NTFS and the other partition suitable format for Linux without loosing data or any malfunctioning.

Please, detailed steps as I'm dummy in installing Linux distros this'll be my first time.

Answer (score 0):

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI probably gives you a good indication what to follow:

> To install Ubuntu in EFI mode:
>
> Use a 64bit disk of Ubuntu (32bit installer does not detect EFI)
>
> Use the last version of Ubuntu. Support for UEFI appeared in 11.10,
>   but has become more reliable in next versions. Support for UEFI
>   SecureBoot appeared in 12.10 and 12.04.2.
>
> Set up your firmware (BIOS) to boot the disk in UEFI mode (see the
>   "Identifying if the computer boots the HDD in EFI mode" paragraph
>   below)
>
> Then: nothing special is required if you use the automatic installer
>   of Ubuntu ("Install Ubuntu alongside others" or "Erase the disk and
>   install Ubuntu"). Important: if you have a pre-installed Windows and
>   you want to keep it, do not choose "Erase the disk and install
>   Ubuntu". if you use the manual partitioning ("Something else"), the
>   difference is that you will have to create and use an EFI partition
>   (see the "Creating an EFI partition" paragraph below).